# Overriding Outlook's Default Sending function

Tags: c#-4.0, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

Im developing a solution for Outlook with VSTO, VS 2010 and Outlook 2010.

I want to override default functionality of Outlook's sending behavior.

Here is the requirement.

When user clicks on Send button, i have to check whether it is an SMS - "IPM.Note.Mobile.SMS". If it is an SMS then i have to give my custom implementation for sending. If it is not an SMS then default sending behavior.

For custom sending part I have to use my own web service and handle it.

**What i want from you is a method/way to override default sending function in Outlook 2010**.

I have read few articles on MSDN, inspector wrappers and enforcing custom business rules, but i didn't get what i want. And i want a pure C# solution not a third party dll like redemption. I tried to be specific as much as i can, i expect the same :)

Please help me :D
Thanks,

Regards -
Sam

Answer (score 6):

You need to handle the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Send` event (`ItemEvents_10_SendEventHandler`). You can see the reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.itemevents_10_event.send.aspx). A rough example is provided below. You can get the message class from the inspector and the active inspector from the application reference.

```
((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)inspector.CurrentItem).Send += new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_SendEventHandler(Inspector_Send);

void Inspector_Send(ref bool Cancel)
        {
            if (IPM.Note.Mobile.SMS) 
            {
               // custom implementation
            }
            else
              Cancel = true; // don't send the message out 
        }
```

Comment: Thank you SilverNinja, Im sorry for the late reply, i was busy with my academic stuff.

Answer (score 4):

Here you have a different solution. Just include this line in your Add-in_StartUp:

```
Application.ItemSend += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend);
```

And of course, the implementation of the event handler:

```
    void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Yihha!!");
        Cancel = true;
    }
```

This will intercept any message you send.